# xml beans in android

Tags: android, spring, xmlbeans

I want to use xml beans in Android. I searched around one day in google and i some places read , i can't use xml beans in Android and Android not have this and now i am confused! I dont know, i can use this or not and if i can't use this, What should i use instead of xml beans? I don't want use maven.

1. xml beans configuration is just in spring?
2. I can use xml beans in Android? if yes xml beans from spring?
3. I read, use xml beans could slow my App. this is true? if yes what should i use instead of this for increase performance app?

I goal from use xml beans this is:

I want to create a bean xml file that i set all of my classes(with my packages) and i want in id tag in bean tag, set a method name from my class. like below: () and with this, i can get SMS method from sendingSMS class with reflection. I mean i can send method name and parameter from this method to reflection class and then call method. This is a training sample for learning android and java bean and reflection in android and then use this in real project.

and I see use xml beans in java like this link ([use beans in java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14419123/about-the-use-of-beans-xml-configuration-file-in-spring-framework-application?rq=1)) but i want use this in android

Thanks for your help :)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can user [XStream Library in Android](http://xstream.codehaus.org/)

Xml Parse would slow your app? No,I think it decides your parse method.

Comment: Thanks for answer. Do you mean, i pars my xml file and again find my package class and etc? Do you answer of another my questions?

Comment: link is down, please change