# Getting an error in beans.xml

Tags: java, xml, spring, javabeans

getting an error in `beans.xml`, please see this [error](http://postimg.org/image/sumpfzrg3/).

I'm making a simple program in Spring, i'm completely beginner, I have two files.

But in `beans.xml`, it shows an error in `<property name="name" //here is an error.. value="Hello World" />`

It says:

> Attribute : name The name of the property, following JavaBean naming
>   conventions.
>
> Data Type : string

here is my full codes:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans 
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd">

    <bean id="helloworld" class="sample1.HelloWorld">
        <property name="message" value="Hello World!!.."/>              
    </bean>

</beans>
```

As i said previously, i have tow files one contain `HelloWorld.java`:

```
package sample1;

public class HelloWorld {
    public String message;

    public void setMessage(){
        this.message=message;
    }

    public void getMessage(){
        System.out.println("Your message: "+message);
    }
}
```

And second contain `MainProgram.java`:

```
package sample1;

import org.springframework.context.ApplicationContext;
import org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext;

public class MainProgram {
    public static void main(String[] args){

        ApplicationContext context=new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("Beans.xml");
        HelloWorld hw=(HelloWorld)context.getBean("helloworld");
        hw.getMessage();
    }
}
```

Help would be appreciated!

Comment: You need to pass a parameter to `setMessage()` -> `setMessage(String message)`. Spring will use it to set the value.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As per Java Beans specification it's not a valid setter method.

It should be

```
public void setMessage(String message){
    this.message=message;
}
```

Comment: hey, thanks it's working and would like to know one more thing.. i'm a beginner and what's the actcual work of `beans.xml` here, i mean what does it do, can you the actual example to understand me?..

Comment: It provide you loose binding between objects. If you want to change the value then you don't need to change the java file. just change it in the configuration file.

Comment: There is an answer here to understand beans.xml http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14419123/about-the-use-of-beans-xml-configuration-file-in-spring-framework-application

Comment: Read more about it [Introduction to the Spring IoC container and beans](http://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/3.0.7.RELEASE/reference/beans.html) in official documentation. Follow the [link](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/92393/what-does-the-spring-framework-do-should-i-use-it-why-or-why-not) to learn more about spring.